# Is it okay to use a single admin user when logging into the API or do I need to use individual user accounts?

Tags: rest-api

I'm working with a client to develop a PHP based application that has its own login system and content but throughout the application there will be interactive forms which will collect data that we'd love to have save back to salesforce contacts and custom objects through the api.

My question is that is it ok to do that with the rules of the API all through one system admin user or do the systems users all need have their own salesforce user accounts?

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. My specific app is going to have users who will be creating contact records, and the app is a collection of interactive forms which will collect even more information about those contacts, some of that data will go on custom object, some will save right back to the contact record.  So in some ways its similar to a mass email tool that creates contacts and stores information about emails sent to them (which I know all use one api user) but they are creating contacts which i guess they own, so?

Comment: Have you thought about using OAuth in your PHP app to obtain a token specific to the user? It seems to me that this would avoid any license ambiguity **and** remove any need for your PHP app to do any of its own ownership/sharing validation. See [this article](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/interact-with-the-forcecom-rest-api-from-php) for a rudimentary example; you can use the same OAuth access token with the SOAP API as well as REST.

Answer (score 8):

I think this largely depends on how you frame the situation. If it's simply an integration between two systems then it's common practice to have an integration user in Salesforce to represent the remote system.

However, if the PHP application is more of a front end for Salesforce used by multiple users, who individually 'own' data records, then you should be using a licence per user, as all you're really doing is creating your own user authentication layer above the platform which is not allowed according to the T&Cs.

**Update**
If the users own contacts as you say, then I'm afraid you're falling on the side of needed licences for each user. If they contacts are shared and visible to all, without being tied to particular users then you could just use the one licence, but it sounds like you'd still be toeing the line in this scenario.

Comment: This is correct - we've butted up against this several times as a Salesforce Partner. As a rule of thumb, if you're not using the external authentication to bypass paying for Salesforce licenses, you're in the clear.

Comment: That all makes sense, but I think my app is still in a little bit of a gray area.

Answer (score 3):

The main consideration is if your architecture is (or can reasonably be perceived to be) designed primarily to circumvent salesforce licensing.  One question to ask is whether you are re-creating any of the core functionality of salesforce in your app.  For example, using a single integration user means you lose visibility on the back-end into who added or changed a record.  If you create fields in your custom objects to keep track of these things and integrate it into your PHP app's user management system, it could reasonably be concluded that you are doing this to get around licensing each user, even though you desire some of the functionality that licensing them would give you.

Answer (score 0):

You should also watch out for record ownership skew. I recommend taking a look at the following post to give you some ideas on how to prevent performance hits.

http://blogs.developerforce.com/engineering/2012/06/architect-salesforce-record-ownership-skew-for-peak-performance-in-large-data-volume-environments.html