# Can I implement my own authentication process in force.com or it is against terms of service?

Tags: force.com, authentication

I am just wondering if it is permited to implement my own authentication process in force.com or it is against terms of service or any rules. Link to official documentation will be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to review this question - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/418/is-it-okay-to-use-a-single-admin-user-when-logging-into-the-api-or-do-i-need-to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By rolling your own users, you wind up losing advantages like individual auditability, password management, and user security - all of which you would essentially need to build into your user management.

http://www.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/misc/salesforce_MSA.pdf

3.2. User Subscriptions. Unless otherwise specified in the applicable Order Form, (i) **Services are purchased as User 
subscriptions and may be accessed by no more than the specified number of Users,** (ii) additional User subscriptions 
may be added during the applicable subscription term at the same pricing as that for the pre-existing subscriptions 
thereunder, prorated for the remainder of the subscription term in effect at the time the additional User subscriptions 
are added, and (iii) the added User subscriptions shall terminate on the same date as the pre-existing subscriptions. 
User subscriptions are for designated Users only and cannot be shared or used by more than one User but may be 
reassigned to new Users replacing former Users who no longer require ongoing use of the Services.

Comment: Thanks Adam!  Sometimes the line of violation vs. non-violation doesn't seem as clear cut, specifically in questions involving api integration such as [Can I use a single admin user when logging into the api or do I need to use the individual user accounts](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/418/is-it-okay-to-use-a-single-admin-user-when-logging-into-the-api-or-do-i-need-to)?

Answer (score 4):

I think it depends on what you're planning to do once you've authenticated someone, it may also depend on which exact edition you're looking at. All the agreements are available here http://www.salesforce.com/company/legal/agreements.jsp

Comment: What to do next would be access the app and manipulate force.com custom objects using the guest profile.

Comment: I think that would be considered user concentration, which i thought was only allowed for database.com editions, but i haven't reviewed the MSA in a really long time.

Comment: I'd think the relevant parts are the definition of "Users" and section 4.3.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing it to purposely avoid paying for portal licenses then my understanding is you are violating the TOS.

How much of Salesforce do you need?  Database.com is extremely cost effective if you need to authenticate a number of users and have them own the data but are providing your own UI.  (Although it does have some architectural considerations, database.com is not going to offer you local relational database level latencies).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want separate authentication would a SAML-based single sign-on solution work for you? You could setup and maintain your own Identity Provider (IdP) and configure Salesforce to use it for authentication purposes. Salesforce would still handle the authorization side, though.

- [Single sign-on Implementation Guide](http://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_single_sign_on.pdf)
- [How to Implement SSO with Force.com](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/How_to_Implement_Single_Sign-On_with_Force.com)

Comment: Idea is to have my own set of users and passwords to login into my app and communicate to force.com custom objects just using the guest profile. Is that acceptable or completely out of context?

Comment: Please see the link I added to your main question. This is probably a case of "ask your account rep."